# Existence and explicit descriptions for left and right Kan extensions and lifts in bicategories of spans

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories, cartesian-closed-categories

Given a category $\mathcal{C}$, it follows from Proposition 4.1 of Day's

> **Brian Day**, *Limit spaces and closed span categories*, Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 420, 1974 ([doi:10.1007/BFb0063100](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0063100)).

That the bicategory $\mathsf{Span}_\mathcal{C}$ of spans in $\mathcal{C}$ has right Kan extensions and right Kan lifts iff $\mathcal{C}$ is locally Cartesian closed.

1. Does $\mathsf{Span}_\mathcal{C}$ also have left Kan extensions and left Kan lifts if (and perhaps only if?) $\mathcal{C}$ is locally Cartesian closed too?
2. What would be explicit descriptions for $\mathrm{Ran}$ and $\mathrm{Rift}$ in $\mathsf{Span}_{\mathcal{C}}$? What about for $\mathrm{Lan}$ and $\mathrm{Lift}$ if these also exist?

---

**Edit:** I was reading

> **Renato Betti**, **Robert F. C. Walters**, *Closed bicategories and variable category theory*, Universita degli Studi di Milano (1985), reprinted in: Reprints in Theory and Applications of Categories, 26 (2020) 1–27 [[tac:tr26]](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/26/tr26abs.html)

where I found the following excerpt from [Example 2.2](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/26/tr26.pdf#page=9):

> [...] the formulae for right extensions and right liftings [in $\mathsf{Span}_{\mathsf{Set}}$] become
> \begin{align*}
>     hom_u(\alpha,\beta)_{ik} &= \Pi_j\hom(\alpha_{ij},\beta_{kj})\\
>     hom^u(\alpha,\beta)_{ik} &= \Pi_j\hom(\alpha_{ji},\beta_{kj}).
> \end{align*}

Here $hom^u$ and $hom_u$ denote right Kan liftings and extensions respectively, where I believe the matrix notation should be interpreted as follows: given a span $A\xleftarrow{f}S\xrightarrow{g}B$, an element $a\in A$, and an element $b\in B$, we write $S_{ab}$ for the set
$$S_{ab}=\{s\in S\ |\ \text{$f(s)=a$ and $g(s)=b$}\}.$$
So given spans $A\xleftarrow{f}S\xrightarrow{g}B$ and $A\xleftarrow{\phi}K\xrightarrow{\psi}X$, the un/straightening isomorphism for fibred and indexed sets would then give
$$\mathrm{Ran}_{S}(K)\cong\coprod_{(b,x)\in B\times X}\prod_{a\in A}\mathsf{Set}(S_{ab},K_{ax}),$$
with the maps $B\leftarrow\mathrm{Ran}_{S}(K)\rightarrow X$ being given by sending an element to its index in the coproduct above.

Is this formula correct, and is there a nicer one?